# How to cancel a drag for UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, drag

I try to drag from one collection view to another, it works fine, except that when I long-press an item and stop there. the item becomes the drag preview version of it and won't fall back to the normal state. How can I stop the active drag?

**only the method is called:**

```
(NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView itemsForBeginningDragSession:(id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

no drop delegate methods are called. drag end method isn't called either

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to abruptly cancel an ongoing drag session (if that is what you desire), and I feel like it will be wrong on UX side of things too

You can however return a cancellation proposal via:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal`

This is a drop-delegate method (requires your `UICollectionView` to conform to `dropDelegate`) that gets called throughout the drag session, till the item gets dropped.

If you `return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)`  on this method, the dragged cell animates back to the origin indicating cancellation. This is probably the best you can do...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    //Do your evaluation

    //if (evaluation requires drop cancellation){
    //    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
    //}
    //else
    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move) //This is the usual behaviour
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also cancel drag events by cancelInteractiveMovement() method, this method will cancel drag events & rearrange old state and when your app is going into background or your controller is changing state, this method will cancel all the interactive movements:

```
collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
```